# How to apply all instagram photo effects in android

Tags: android, instagram, photo, effects

Hi Guys I am developing a similar app like Instagram, tumbler, Filker etc. But I stuck in photo effects actually I need photo effects like Instagram.

I generated some new effects by the help of Color Matrix, saturation, image masking etc. But I am not able to get similar effect like Instagram have.

Any know about instagram photo effects color matrix or other fectors which give me exact effects or any library which provide me similar effects.

I want to include one thing that I create some instagram effects by the help masking of images but that's not actual one. I am ready to R&D but give some way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this link http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html

Comment: and this one too http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

Comment: @Shink, I try xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials. But in this blog they are using looping concept and this is very time consuming.

Comment: Try the other one as it uses OpenGL

Comment: @Shink, blog grishma102.blogsopt.in/2013/10/.... is not below 14 Android SDK. I can not give min sdk 14, my app work from min OS froyo. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram actually acquired a company to enhance its photo and video filters,for which this app is so famous. So this should give you an idea on how elaborated is their concept.

However there is a library OpenCV. This is by far the most efficient opensource library for image/video processing. It is also used in advanced robotics and AI projects.

It also has a JAVA wrapper called JavaCV. Actually, OpenCV is written in C, and JavaCv is a java wrapper for it.

This could be your solution. But again, this library does not have direct functions implemented for a specific effect. You need to use its basic functions to manipulate your image/video. It will involve some RnD for sure, but I guess the effort will be worth it.

Other than this(OpenCv/JavaCv), you may find some libraries on GitHub to serve your need.These libraries may provide you with direct functions like, toSepia(bitmap) etc, but your app's image filters  will be limited to scope of the Library you choose.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried openGL and by the help of this I can change RGB and alpha of photo and I also create some photo effect not all(Instagram), by the help of photoshoped image+9 pathed image+ masking. But what actually I need to know that how instagram acheieved these different effects. What they are using to create "Hudson", "Rise", "Sepia" etc effect. What color matrix or any thing more. I can create more effects Instagram have but basically client want similar effects. That's why I stuck in this step.

Comment: But now I will use OpenCV. Thanks to a new way.