# Using the filter effects of Android's Fotos app

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, instagram, photo

I'm currently working on a Android photo management app. I would like to have "Instagramm like" photo filters. But actually Android can do it much better itself with the pre-installed Photo App.
See here:

[image]

The App on the right hand side is the one I'm referring to:
[image]

I already had a look at the developer guides but nothing is described there.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

In general: How can I make use of those filters without implementing them on myself and without forcing the user to switch between apps.

Does anyone have any hints for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actual if you want don't want to switch the app then you have to implement it in your app using any image processing library or drawing the image on canvas then make the changes using different color effects.Adding layer on canvas and changing the color scheme somewhat and saving image again.Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730252/how-to-apply-all-instagram-photo-effects-in-android?rq=1

Comment: i develop these filters in ndk and open cv i'm giving you a link do follow it and then you can develop every filter. check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218438/open-cv-filter-results-black-lining-on-image

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. In case I don't want to implement it: Is there a way to access the preinstalled Photo App via an intent and use it's photo editing capabilities?